# Print min and max with awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

Why wont this awk script work, where I want to print the min and max of an input by just reading the data once.  I would also like to initialize the min and max variable with the first value of the data.

Say I have a file

```
a 14
a 34
a 234
a 2345
a 1
a 24
```

I am using awk to print the min and max with:

```
cat test.txt | awk 'BEGIN {min=$2; max=$2} {if ($2 < min) {min=$2}; if ($2 > max) {max=$2} } END {print "min: " min "max: " max}'
```

But I am getting a result of:

```
min: max: 2345
```

I dont understand why min is set to blank?

Comment: The `BEGIN{}` block is executed *before* reading the file, therefore the
variables `min` and `max` are assigned to a null string then. In the following
loop, `min` is evaluated as numeric value 0 in the comparison and not updated.
Try to put `NR==1 {min=$2; max=$2; next}` instead of the `BEGIN{}` block.

Comment: What should the output be if the input file is empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `BEGIN {}` block is processed before the first line so `$2` is undefined.

```
$ cat file
a 14
a 34
a 234
a 2345
a 1
a 24
$ awk 'NR == 1  { min = max = $2; next }
       $2 > max { max = $2 }
       $2 < min { min = $2 }
       END      { print "min: " min ", max: " max }' file
min: 1, max: 2345
```

Answer (score 0):

All numeric values in awk are stored in floating-point format, and there are no equivalents to C `INT_MIN`, `INT_MAX`, so you simply need to pick the range of values you wish to handle and initialize your `max` to the minimum possible value in the range you wish to consider, and `min` to the maximum possible value in the range you wish to consider.

For signed integer values, simply choosing the min/max values for 32-bit a signed integer is reasonable. For example, you can do:

```sh
 awk '
  BEGIN { min=2147483647; max=-2147483648 } 
  $2 > max { max=$2 } 
  $2 < min { min=$2 }
  END { print "max: ", max ORS "min: ", min }
' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your data in `file`, you would get:

```
$ awk '
>   BEGIN { min=2147483647; max=-2147483648 }
>   $2 > max { max=$2 }
>   $2 < min { min=$2 }
>   END { print "max: ", max ORS "min: ", min }
> ' file
max:  2345
min:  1
```

Which is what you were looking for.

Comment: Don't use arbitrary initial numbers, just always init your min and max variables to the first values read.

Comment: I see the logic, the numbers are hardly arbitrary though.

Comment: There may be some better word. "specific" maybe? or "explicit"? But you get the point...